# MacOS 12.3.1 Full Disk Access problem

Tags: system-settings, privacy, preferences, mdm

We use an MDM solution to manage devices. A .mobileconfig 'profile' grants all the necessary access for Ivanti File Director, that works perfectly fine when the rights were granted on an earlier version of MacOS however when we start the application the first time on 12.3.1 the Full Disk Access request just jumps back and forth. (even if we grant it manually with admin rights)

With one word with 12.3.1 something has changed and we're unable to figure it out. Ivanti support ticket is open and we're waiting for their answer however it'd be good to know that we dig in the right direction.

I'm not sure I can post the .mobileconfig file, since it may contain sensitive information.

Thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: what was the "earlier version of macOS?" 12.3 or 12.1 or even 11?

Answer (score 4):

So Ivanti support came back to us and the solution is surreal. At least for me.
12.3.1 privacy preference changed.
So the solution for us is to give full disk access to terminal, then

```
touch /Users/USERNAME-IN-QUESTION/Library/Safari/CloudTabs.db
chown USERNAME-IN-QUESTION /Users/USERNAME-IN-QUESTION/Library/Safari/CloudTabs.db
```

Then, to be safe n secure, take away the full disk access from terminal.

After this, Ivanti File Director starts and runs as expected.

Beats me what Safari has got to do with all this but it does work. They're working on a built in permanent, touch free solution also.